# Why are we assigning node to a pointer in linked list

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, list, linked-list

Please refer to the code below

***cur*** in the code is a node and so it consists of a data value and a variable  called next. I don't understand line 15:

```
cur = cur.next
```

i.e Why are we assigning cur.next to a node (i.e. cur))? Similarly, in line 16 ```
cur.next=new_node

```
... why are are we assigning a node (i.e called new_node) to cur.next when cur.next is not even a node?

I haven't found an answer in many youtube videos, stack exchange webpage, google, linkedlist and other searches.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qan4R.png
```

Comment: Perhaps you could put the code here in the question so that way it is readily available for people that wish to help you. Images do not promote an easy way for code help, as copying and pasting becomes impossible.

Comment: I tried. It keeps outputting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending a new node to the linked list. So you set the current node to the head (The first thing in the chain). Now you want to add the link to the end of the chain, and there are two ways to do that. You can either insert a new link to the beginning (thus changing head and not what is done here), or you can insert a new link to the end of the chain (what is going on here). So curr is a temporary node at this point, and it points to the head (the first link). We know there is not another link if curr.next == none, and we wish to add an item to the end of the link. So this code uses a while loop to change the position of insertion. `curr` becomes `curr.next` (if there is one) continuously until `curr` is the last link of the chain, meaning `curr.next` is the empty space where the next link should go. Now you insert the new_node to the end of the chain with the assignment `curr.next = new_node`

It might be easier to picture linked lists as chains going from left to right.

The head is at the left, and this code wants to insert a new link to the chain at the right side. So it starts at the far left, and traverses down each link until it realizes there is no more link on the right. Then it inserts the new link.

You also seem to be confused on the order of operations. Operations on the right of the equal sign will be assigned to the value on the left side. So `x = y`
does not set the value of y to be the value of x, but rather sets the value of x to be the value of y.

Comment: When you say: "So x = y does not set the value of y to be the value of x, but rather sets the value of x to be the value of y.", 

would line 15 be understood as we are setting  the node cur to be the pointer cur.next? Similarly, line 16 would be interprated as setting the pointer cur.next to be the node new_node? This concept is my confusion. Are we allowed to set a pointer to equal a node when a node consists of pointer + data value?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. In Python you reference the value directly, no need to think in pointers. So cur.next is a reference to the next node instance. There's no need to dereference pointers or get a pointer to a value. Assigning to the left hand side sets the left hand side to reference the value on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to clarify this: So when we write cur = cur.next, this means we are setting the node cur (which consists of cur.next)  to reference the right hand side (cur.next)?

sorry, i am a bit rusty on python. I'm still learning. If you know any sources regarding references in python that i could read up on, please let me know.

Comment: @Dan This is exactly the case! Sorry it took a bit to respond.

Answer (score 0):

The key insight here is that the next variable is a Node. Although it seems weird that an object can hold an instance of the same class, there aren't actually any issues with it. A linked list works by having at each node both the data that the node actually holds and a variable which points to the next node in the chain. By saying `cur = cur.next`, we're saying advance the cur node to the node it says is next in the chain. Once we reach the end of the chain, i.e. where `cur.next == None`, we want to put this new node in at the end, so we say "instead of saying the next node doesn't exist, the new next node is the one I want to add on to the end".

Comment: Can you please clarify your sentence: ."By saying cur = cur.next, we're saying advance the cur node to the node it says is next in the chain.cur is a node that contains data value and the variable next." I still don't see why are we able to set a node (i.e. cur) to a variable in a node(i..e cur.next)? That is main main confusion.